# Apache Karaf - wait for bundle

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

This is a little embarrassing considering I have been meddling around with Karaf for a while now.

I have a service implementation bundle and a CXF-REST bundle.  If I throw in the REST bundle before the ServiceImpl bundle into my deploy folder, it waits for the service bundle for a few seconds and then goes into a `Failed` state.  Obviously, all goes well if I do it in sequence - ServiceImpl first and REST next. I wanted my REST service to wait forever until the ServiceImpl is deployed (just like the rest of the OSGi bundles)

My guess is that there is some place where I should be increasing the timeout to wait forever.  This guess is based on the fact that for a PaxExam test, I should do so.

```
@Inject
@Filter(timeout = 300000)
BootFinished bootFinished;
```

(source : [KarafTestSupport.java](https://github.com/oliverlietz/sling/blob/trunk/contrib/launchpad/karaf/org.apache.sling.launchpad.karaf-integration-tests/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/launchpad/karaf/testing/KarafTestSupport.java))

Am I looking at the wrong place or should I be looking at other places for hints like Activator or Export/Import packages?

I understand that deploying as a .kar file along with the the rest of the libraries (I deploy the dependencies as a .kar) would solve it but I do not want to do that for the REST and Impl bundles  because of faster deployments (and bandwidth sizes - I am on EC2).

Comment: is it karaf 3.0? did you use the bundle:info command on the bundle which fails? It should show you the reason for it to fail.

Comment: Yes @AchimNierbeck.  The reason is just because it timed out of waiting for the service impl bundle.  Just posted the question on the karaf mailing list and got it fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Earlier I didnt have any timeout set.

```
<reference  id=“xxxServiceBean"
           interface="com.nutraspace.coreservices.search.service.impl.base.NewsSearchService">
</reference>
```

Now that I have set it to 10 minutes, it works great.  Tested and verified.

```
<reference timeout="600000" id=“xxxServiceBean"
           interface="com.nutraspace.coreservices.search.service.impl.base.NewsSearchService">
</reference>
```

Here's the link to the thread

http://karaf.922171.n3.nabble.com/Waiting-for-dependent-bundle-td4032415.html